# Navigation Bar without Refreshing page content

Tags: jquery, navigation, reload

I have the following link structure (navigation bar) on a page:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_get_thumbs > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_get_thumbs=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, 
    $queryString_get_thumbs); ?>"><img src="First.gif" /></a>
        <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
     <td><?php if ($pageNum_get_thumbs > 0) { // Show if not first page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_get_thumbs=%d%s", $currentPage, 
     max(0, $pageNum_get_thumbs - 1), $queryString_get_thumbs); ?>"><img 
    src="Previous.gif" /></a>
        <?php } // Show if not first page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_get_thumbs < $totalPages_get_thumbs) { // Show if 
     not last page ?>
        <a class="nav_link" href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_get_thumbs=%d%s", 
   $currentPage, min($totalPages_get_thumbs, $pageNum_get_thumbs + 1), 
   $queryString_get_thumbs); ?>"><img src="Next.gif" /></a>
        <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
    <td><?php if ($pageNum_get_thumbs < $totalPages_get_thumbs) { // Show if 
   not last page ?>
        <a href="<?php printf("%s?pageNum_get_thumbs=%d%s", $currentPage, 
        $totalPages_get_thumbs, $queryString_get_thumbs); ?>"><img 
     src="Last.gif" /></a>
        <?php } // Show if not last page ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any way that one can click on any of the links without refreshing the entire page? This is what it looks like on the page:

[image: Thumbnail navigation bar]

I have tried Ajax (onclick GET method) and other suggestion from various sites, but I am having no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind click event to link and pass javascript:void(0) in href. as shown below, This will stop refreshing of the page.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="yourFunction(params)"><img src="First.gif" /></a>
```

and create yourFunction(params) in the code.

**javascript:void(0) will stop page refreshing.** And onclick will get fired once you click the link, You can write your remaining logic there.

You can write link like shown below.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="yourFunction(<?php printf("%s?pageNum_get_thumbs=%d%s", $currentPage, 0, 
    $queryString_get_thumbs); )"><img src="First.gif" /></a>
```

And function like below.

```
function yourFunction(params){

window.location.href = params;// or any other logic as per your requiriement;
}
```

Comment: Thank you amit. At least it steerd me in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

I added a variable called params:

```
$params = explode("&", $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Then changed the link to:

```
<a onclick="next_slide('<?php printf("%s?pageNum_get_thumbs=%d%s", 
$currentPage, min($totalPages_get_thumbs, $pageNum_get_thumbs + 1), 
$queryString_get_thumbs); ?>')" href="#">Next</a>
```

Then I added the Jquery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function next_slide(params) {
  $('#container').load('<?php printf("%s?pageNum_get_thumbs=%d%s", 
 $currentPage, min($totalPages_get_thumbs, $pageNum_get_thumbs + 1), 
 $queryString_get_thumbs); ?>');

}

</script>
```

All the images are located in the container DIV and repeats three at a time.

And voila! It works! Hopefully this can help someone in the future and prevent then from banging their heads against the $devrocks